# How can I move a file into the documents directory in iOS 13?

Tags: swift, iphone, persistence, ios13

I'm building a video posting iOS app that needs to handle offline syncing. After a user takes a video, I need to persist it on the device in case the app quits before it uploads. Before iOS13, I was doing this with no problem in the documents directory:

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let docsFileUrl documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("somevideofile.mov")
try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempFileUrl, to: docsFileUrl)
```

Since iOS13 came out, my app crashes when I try to move the item from the temp directory to the docs directory. This is the error:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“trim.42E4B9EC-6166-4265-BE28-E57C480244B6.MOV” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “Documents”."
```

Anyone know how I can simply persist a file in iOS13?